# serialport and socket.io issue

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Why can't I use serialport.on inside the socket.io connection? It doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't print anything either. It works correctly if I move it outside of the socket.io block, but I don't know how to send the data through the socket in that case. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
 // socket connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('User Connected');

 // socket disconnection
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
console.log('User disconnected!');
});

 // serialport connection. (NOT WORKING WHEN INSIDE THE SOCKET BLOCK)
serialport.on("open", function () {
console.log('open');
serialport.on('data', function(data) {
console.log('data received: ' + data);
  });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out. You have to first open the serial connection somewhere outside of the socket with serialport.on('open'). Connection will stay open and then you can use serialport.on('data', function(data){}); inside the socket to receive data and to emit it to clients. For some reason it sometimes runs the function multiple times though. Maybe the serial needs to be flushed at some point or something.